# Setting up a server using Boost-ASIO for Wireshark to connect to and receive packets?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost-asio, wireshark

I am trying to create a simple server using ASIO in order to send packets to Wireshark to view them using the remote interfaces feature.

This is the code that sets up the server and waits for a connection.

```
void server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port)
{

    tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

    for (;;)
    {
        auto pSock = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);

        auto handler = [pSock](const boost::system::error_code& err) -> void
        {
            if (err)
            {
                pSock->close();
                return;
            }
            auto buf = connectToNamedPipe();
            streamOut(pSock, buf);
            pSock->close();
        };
        std::cout << "Awaiting connection" << std::endl;
        a.async_accept(*pSock, handler);
        io_service.run();
    }
}
```

This is the code that sends a packet once a client connects

```
void streamOut(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> pSock, const std::pair<std::unique_ptr<char[]>, std::size_t>& b)
{
    ::boost::system::error_code ec;

    write(*pSock, ::boost::asio::buffer(b.first.get(), b.second));

    for (;;) 
    {
        char a;
        std::cin >> a;
        if (a == 'e')
            return;
    }
}
```

However when Wireshark does connect (using the remote interfaces tab in the manage interfaces dialog), it hangs and stops respond until the close this application. Is there some other data I need to send to Wireshark before it starts sending data? Am I just sending data incorrectly? Is the server not set up correctly?

Comment: Running `run()` in a loop without `.reset()` isn't supported AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is a "wire-tap".

You don't "send packets to it for viewing" and it doesn't "connect" to your application.

Instead, Wireshark just taps into the NIC and sees all the packets that get transmitted. So, instead connect to your server with a regular client (like `netcat`) and have Wireshark monitor the NIC(s) involved.

You can, for simplicity, capture the traffic on all network adaptors at once, I believe.

Comment: Yes that's for sniffing on the wire. But i'm specifically talking about using the remote interfaces feature.

Comment: Oh wow. That's a feature? You might want to make that bit of information a bit clearer in your question. Will remove my "answer" once you do